# Трудности при работе с атрибутом hidden

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

Хочу написать скрипт, которые при клике на заголовке скрывает div, когда тот виден, и, наоборот, когда div скрыт, то, чтобы отображался снова. То, что я предлагаю не работает, в чем проблема? И еще, почему когда я атрибуту hidden в html ставлю значение false, то получаю обратное действие на отображаемой странице (элемент пропадает, а не наоборот отображается, как было бы логически предположить)?

```js
function clcHead() {
  if (document.getElementById('txt-area').hidden == false) {
    document.getElementById('txt-area').hidden = true;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('txt-area').hidden == true) {
    document.getElementById('txt-area').hidden = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 onclick="clcHead()">Click on header</h1>
  <div id="txt-area" hidden="false">
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Во-первых, используйте `else if`, или же просто `if else`. Во-вторых, атрибуту `hidden` в HTML не пишется значение, одно его присутствие - это true, а отсутствие - false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может вы имеете ввиду `display:none`? Для чего вы используете атрибут hidden?

```js
const header = document.querySelector("#header")

const handleClick = () => {
  const txtArea = document.querySelector("#txt-area")
  txtArea.hidden = !txtArea.hidden
}

header.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

```css
#txt-area {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Click on header</h1>
<div id="txt-area" hidden="false">#
</div>
```

Comment: Я бы использовал `const`, вместо `let`. А так же `div.hidden = !div.hidden`.